# Download dialog not appearing for the second time using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using the following code to download a word file in C# (Javascript). First time when I click the button download dialog appears in IE and then closes the parent window. But for the second time, if I open the same window and click on download parent widow disappears but download dialog does not appear. So my question is am I missing anything.

```
javaScript = "OpenWindow('" + url + "', 'wndOpenSave');$('#" + btnClose.ClientID + "').click();";

System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "RenderOpenSaveDialogue", javaScript, true);
```

My javascript code is like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function resizeWindow() {
            if (document.body.scrollHeight > 700) {
                window.resizeTo(document.body.scrollWidth + 60, document.body.scrollHeight - 60);
            }
            else {
                window.resizeTo(document.body.scrollWidth + 60, document.body.scrollHeight + 70);
            }
            window.moveTo(200, 0);
        }

        attachEvent('onload', resizeWindow);

        function OpenWindow(url, args) {
            if (url != "" && url != null) {
                window.open(encodeURI(url),
                    '_blank',
                    'height=300,width=300,location=no,' +
                    'menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,' +
                    'status=no,toolbar=no');
            }
        }

        function ClosetopWindow() {
            //    debugger;
            top.window.close();
            //// window.setTimeOut(function () { window.close(); }, 5000);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your OpenWindow() method in javascript?

Comment: @Atk done, please check.

Comment: OK.I think you are getting null url second time. Can you just add an else part in your function and add an alert to check if your url is null.

Comment: @Atk url for second time is same as first time. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the parent first then opening save dialog resolved my issue.

```
javaScript = " $('#" + btnClose.ClientID + "').click();OpenWindow('" + url + "', 'wndOpenSave');";
```

In my opinion, issue was that it was opening a dialog window and then closing that in the next statement.